# Why do many of the GUI CObjects ie(CButton) have to be put on the heap as opposed to the stack?

Tags: c++, mfc

If I try and define a GUI button CButton like `CButton btn;` I get an error-> because I tried putting it on the stack

But if I do `CButton *btn = new CButton();`  It works and this is put on the heap.

Why can't I put CButton objects on the stack?

Comment: What library are you using? Where are these `CButton` objects coming from? Is this MFC, or something else entirely? And what error do you receive?

Comment: This decision is not about the heap or the stack. It is about the storage duration, and possibly polymorphism. Also, avoid using "naked" `new` like this, as it will easily lead to memory leaks and other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an issue of storage duration.  Using MFC, the purpose of a CButton is so the user can click it, which generates an event, which you can then handle.  All of this indicates that the lifetime of the CButton must extend beyond the lifetime of the function that creates it.  In a typical MFC dialog class (CDialog), a CButton is a member variable, so its lifetime is the lifetime of the class instance.  If you instead declare the CButton variable in the constructor it will go out of scope and be destroyed when the constructor ends.

There are some unusual situations where you might want to create buttons based on a decision not known until run-time.  In that case, the above comment about not using a naked "new" is important.  Use a smart pointer (or a container of smart pointers) to hold the CButton* you create, so they will be cleaned up automatically.  Those smart pointers, or the container, would need to be created at class scope.

Comment: Do note that the destructor for many of these window wrapper classes does not necessarily delete the native window. C++ object creation and Windows object creation are not equivalent in the MFC world.

Answer (score 4):

There is a common idiom in MFC which I haven't seen anywhere else. It is possible to create a "temporary" object which will be cleaned up automatically. The cleanup occurs during certain stages of MFC processing, such as the message loop.

```
CButton * btn = (CButton *) FromHandle(hwnd);
```

The `FromHandle` function returns a pointer to a `CWnd` object, but you don't know where that object came from. You *should not* try to delete the pointer, and don't rely on the pointer being valid beyond the current scope - never save it to a member variable! MFC will delete the object if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know MFC, but my guess is, that your CButton, which is allocated on the stack runs out of scope, thus being destroyed.
Accessing this instance of the button from somewhere else will then cause an access violation.

Answer (score 1):

1)  As many others have replied, it has to do with the scope of the variable.  By making it local to a function, it ends its life when the function exits.

2) Stack space is much more limited than heap space, especially with multiple threads.  A typical win32 process has less than a megabyte of stack allocation, but can have thousands of megabytes of heap.